# Tricky Classpath issue

Tags: java, jar, classpath, weblogic-10.x

Working on an existing application, it runs on Weblogic as a massive ear file.

There is custom code, written by my organization, as well as code written by the vendor that all runs on one classpath when weblogic starts up.

Some of our custom code uses spring 1.2, in the latest version of the vendors code, they use spring3.   So we cannot get the ear to completely work unless we can get each component the spring version it needs in order to function.  But since they are both using the classpath that weblogic is started on, either spring1.2 or spring 3.0 will be first depending on the order in the classpath.

Am I stuck?  Missing something?  I've never had to deal with classpaths at this level.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Classloaders use a delegation model when loading a class. The classloader implementation first checks its cache to see if the requested class has already been loaded. This class verification improves performance in that its cached memory copy is used instead of repeated loading of a class from disk. If the class is not found in its cache, the current classloader asks its parent for the class. Only if the parent cannot load the class does the classloader attempt to load the class. If a class exists in both the parent and child classloaders, the parent version is loaded. This delegation model is followed to avoid multiple copies of the same form being loaded. Multiple copies of the same class can lead to a ClassCastException.

Think setting the following in weblogic.xml might help

**prefer-web-inf-classes Element**

The **weblogic.xml** Web application deployment descriptor contains a *prefer-web-inf-classes* element (a sub-element of the  element). By default, this element is set to False. Setting this element to True subverts the classloader delegation model so that class definitions from the Web application are loaded in preference to class definitions in higher-level classloaders. This allows a Web application to use its own version of a third-party class, which might also be part of WebLogic Server. See "weblogic.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements".*

*When using this feature, you must be careful not to mix instances created from the Web application's class definition with issuances created from the server's definition. If such instances are mixed, a ClassCastException results.*

Refer to the URL below

[Oracle Weblogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG285)